# No property or field 'x' exists in type 'Object' - Dynamic linq

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a property of type Object.

```
class Test
{
    public Object obj { get; set; } // This "obj" can be of type Test1 or other type 
    .....
}

class Test1
{
    public int a = 1;
    public int b = 2;
}

List<Test> myList = new List<Test>{new Test() {obj = new Test1()}} // This contains some values.
```

Now I want to sort "myList" based on "obj" values with sort string known dynamically using:

```
myList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("obj.a ascending, obj.b descending");
```

This is when I get error. I have tried type casting but that does not help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `AsQueryable` is neither correct here nor should it be necessary. You should almost never manually call `AsQueryable`. Queryables are used for code that will be passed to a LINQ provider and usually compiled to SQL (though there are other possibilities).

Comment: You are doing some very confusing things here.  If the intent is to have `Test` wrap `Test1`, then be explicit about it and define `obj` as a `Test1` rather than an `object`.  Trying to roll your own generics rarely ends well.

Comment: @48klocs I made a mistake in initializing the list. myList is a list of test objects, and test object contains obj property which can be of type test1, test2 or anything else which will be decided in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The way to sort in LINQ is:

```
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(obj => obj.a).ThenByDescending(obj => obj.b).ToList();
```

If "dynamic" in the title of your question refers to building your condition in run-time, maybe you should look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, but in my case I just had a list of objects (List) and I had to sort it dynamically. I used activator to create an instance of IList of the type of object, added all the objects, then sorted it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know what `obj` is because it is of type `Object`.

The only way around this is either implementing an interface on your types that will have a common `a` and `b` or a using `dynamic` instead of `Object`. However, using `dynamic` is not the best way to go about these issues unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is `myList` expect the object of type `Test` not `Test1`. You need to set the value of `obj` property of `Test` like this

```
List<Test> myList = new List<Test>{new Test(){ obj=new Test1() }};
```

Now you want to apply the sorting over the `Test1` object so you need to cast that object  into type of `Test1` like this and then apply the sorting.

```
myList.OrderBy(x => ((Test1)x.obj).a).OrderByDescending(x => ((Test1)x.obj).b);
```

Comment: He says in his comment though that `obj` could be anything. It may not be `Test1`.

Comment: yes in that case he need to cast the `myList` in required datatype.

Comment: Well, he would need to cast in the lambda expression. His list isn't of type `Test1`, but of `Test` which has a `obj` property that *could* be `Test1`. His list is still full of `Test`s

Comment: @TyCobb thanks for pointing the good point. Check my update to see whether this was meant by you.